# Url error in retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Here the code which shows error url at run time:

```
    String FULL_url = "abcd";


    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

    Interceptor logging = interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();

    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager)).addInterceptor(logging).build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();

    RerofitInterface api = retrofit.create(RerofitInterface.class);

    Call<SportsResultItems> call = api.getFeed(FULL_url);
```

Here the URL shows some errors instead of `&` it is showing `%`.

```
@GET("Sports/{user}/09/2017&ToDate=29/09/2017")
Call<SportsResultItems> getFeed(@Path("user") String user);
```

Comment: I think this part of Url is wrong...check once...{user}/09/2017&ToDate=29/09/2017

Comment: not that i am getting correct answer in postman

Comment: what error your are getting?show logs

Comment: Error 404 :   SportsSearch%3FsearchType----> in this line % is not in actual url while running it shows this .

Comment: Are you using localhost url??

Comment: yes its local host

Comment: Your url is getting encoded, %3f is ? in encoded form